# Aggregation on the different values of a parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am parsing URLs such as:

```
example.org/index.html?parameter_1=value_1&parameter_2=value_2
example.org/index.html?parameter_1=value_1&parameter_2=value_3
example.org/index.html?parameter_1=value_4&parameter_2=value_3
example.org/index.html?parameter_1=value_5&parameter_2=value_4
```

*There are a lot more parameters by url, and they are not always the same, it just to simplify.*

I would like to get the *different values of parameter_2 when parameter_1 equals value_1* and how many hit I have for each value (in this case "value_2"/1 and "value_3"/1).

Here is my mapping:

```
"my_index" : {
  "mappings" : {
    "urls" : {
        ...
        "page" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
        "parameters" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "name" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
            "value" : { "type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which give me entries like this:

```
{
  "page": "example.org/index.html",
  "parameters": [
    { "name": "parameter_1", "value": "value_1" },
    { "name": "parameter_2", "value": "value_2" }
  ]
}
```

If I want to do that but on the pages, I can do a filtered aggregation like this :

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "sitecodes": {
            "filter": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "parameters",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "parameters.name": "parameter_1"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "term": {
                                        "parameters.value": "value_1"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "pages": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "page"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I cannot find a way do to the same on the value of parameter_2.

As a workaround I could duplicate the information in my mapping in order to have entries like this:

```
{
  "page": "example.org/index.html",
  "parameter_1": "value_1",
  "parameters": [
    { "name": "parameter_1", "value": "value_1" },
    { "name": "parameter_2", "value": "value_2" }
  ]
}
```

But I believe there is a better way to do that, even if I haven't find it yet.

Any idea ?

Comment: If inside your must you use an terms query or multi match query? that accepts multiple terms on clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you use a combination of the [Nested Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) and [Filter Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) you can achieve the results you are looking for.

The `nested` aggregation allows you to aggregate on your nested documents. But, each of your nested documents contains a "name" and a "value". Since you are only interested in the distinct values for "parameter_2", you need to filter for where the "name" is "parameter_2". Lastly, you can do a `terms` aggregation on the "value" field.

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sitecodes": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "parameters",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "parameters.name": "parameter_1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "parameters.value": "value_1"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "my_nested": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "parameters"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "parmFilter": {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "parameters.name": "parameter_2"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "groupByValue": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "parameters.value",
                    "size": 10
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which returned the following results as expected (using your example data):

```
...
"aggregations": {
  "sitecodes": {
     "doc_count": 2,
     "my_nested": {
        "doc_count": 4,
        "parmFilter": {
           "doc_count": 2,
           "groupByValue": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "value_2",
                    "doc_count": 1
                 },
                 {
                    "key": "value_3",
                    "doc_count": 1
                 }
              ]
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Had to use params_exploded.name and params_exploded.value instead of name and value in parmFilter but it works... Thank you for saving me hours !

Comment: @Pandawan yes, sorry about that. I tested on version 1.7 before ES required fully qualified field names in `nested` queries and aggs. I will edit my answer to be compatible with all versions. Glad I could help!